# In app notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Is there is something like In App Notification?(Other than push notification) if yes please give me some link for information on it. I had google but does not found anything important.

Comment: try this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

Comment: @Diva thanks for response. is that mean "In app notification" is another term for "Local notification"/ (or pull notification)?  If I want some new data from server but dont want to use Push notification then I have to ping server every time for asking- is there is any new thing is there?

Comment: you can tigrrer service after every x mins.

Comment: @PPD , you can use socket connection for communication with server. You have to update IP address of yours to server in regular interval say in each 10 mins. If server has your IP address , server will send you message. This is the basic mechanism how normal chat application like Whatsapp do.

Comment: push-messaging-vs-in-app-messaging     http://info.localytics.com/blog/push-messaging-vs-in-app-messaging-whats-the-difference-for-app-marketing

Answer (score 1):

**In App Notifications**

It is a new type of notification that is displayed inside the app. Users will see it only if they are inside the app.

There are usually two types of in app notifications or in app messaging:

1. Intrusive
2. Non-Intrusive

**The Intrusive In App Notifications** are usually created when you do an action inside the app and the app developer wants to promote something to you.

For example, if there is a free fitness app. At the end of doing some exercise, you are asked to view one video ad in exchange for the free exercise that you received or you can be asked to leave a review on Google Play Store or Apple Store for the app.

**The Non-Intrusive In App Notifications** are notifications that sit inside a screen and can be viewed whenever the user is in the app and feels like they should do it.

This type of messages can help app owners to share personalised recommendations, offers, discount codes or updates with their users.

Usually, they are used when you want to reach users that have opted out of push notifications or other communication channels.

Some apps will allow their customers to reply with feedback to their notifications.

There are software development kits from [Apptegrity](https://apptegrity.io) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging) or [Apptentive](https://www.apptentive.com/features/message-center/) that help Android and iOS apps to integrate easily with non-intrusive in-app notifications.

I hope this answers your question.